# how to notify other users when git commit or push

Tags: git, github

I am not using any review tools (e.g. pull request), and just want to email notify the whole team if anyone is executing git commit or git push (notification is just for their information purpose, no need for their review). Wondering if any solutions either from either git command line or github.com setup.

Comment: You cannot really notify others on `git commit` (since that happens locally), but you could totally add webhooks that notify users of pushes to GitHub. Note that users can actually tell GitHub [to send notifcation emails for pushes to repositories on their own](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-notifications-for-pushes-to-a-repository/).

Comment: @poke, vote up and thanks. Wondering for your guide, it will send email notification when `commit` or when `push`?

Comment: it will notify when `push`.

Comment: @AntonSizikov, why I am asking since the confusion from this statement "commits to a pull request ", confuse me if it means when `git commit` other than when `git push`. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GitHub includes a built-in webhook to send emails for pushes in a repository. You can set that up from the “Webhooks & services” configuration of a repository. See [this official manual](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-notifications-for-pushes-to-a-repository/#enabling-email-service-notifications-for-pushes-to-your-repository) for more details.

In addition, you could set up your own webhooks to send out notifications. As for notifications on committing, you *could* do that too using normal Git hooks, but since commits happen locally (and offline), every member of your team would be required to set up that Git hook and also agree to send out emails automatically whenever they commit. I personally wouldn’t want that at all. It’s a strong feature that you are able to push only when you are ready with your commits, so you shouldn’t take that away from users (and I personally commit *a lot* more often than my final history shows—those commits are not meant for others but only for me).

Comment: Thanks poke, vote up. The document is a bit confusing to me from this statement "commits to a pull request ", confuse me if it means when git commit other than when git push. Your advice is appreciated. :)

Comment: That sentence only applies to individual user notifications (which only work inside pull requests). You are looking for general notifications on push, and those you get with webhooks.

Comment: Thanks poke, vote up for your comments. Confused what do you mean "sentence only applies to individual user notifications (which only work inside pull requests)", I think the page your point out if to handle `git push` scenario only other than `git commit` scenario?

Comment: BTW, you can see the page title is `Managing notifications for pushes to a repository`, I think it is for the context of `git push` only. So it is why I am lost as you said "That sentence only applies to individual user notifications (which only work inside pull requests)". Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong. :)

Comment: That very first sentence of that page which you quoted above only applies to GitHub’s pull requests. Everything else on that page is about getting more detailed notifications for all pushes. And no, as I explained in my answer, this only covers pushes, not commits.

Comment: Thanks poke, vote up and it seems only repo owner could set up web hook?

Comment: Thanks poke, I use comamnd `git push origin <some branch>` for pull request, i.e. leveraging `git push` command. I am a bit confused what are the differences between  "applies to GitHub’s pull requests" and " for all pushes" in your comments, as both seems using `git push` the same thing. :)

Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: [Pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/) are a completely separate concept.

Comment: Thanks poke, vote up for your reply. I understand what is pull request and used often. My question is, from the page statement, "commits to a pull request", what is the related git command, is it `git push origin <some branch>`?

Comment: That refers to pushing to a branch that is currently being used as a pull request, yes. In those cases, GitHub will automatically pick up those commits and add them to the pull request.

Comment: Thanks poke, vote up for the reply. As your insightful comments, `commit` is for local operation, so the statement "when a user commits to a pull request that you're subscribed to either by email", I think it is not correct, since as you said we do not want to be notified by local commit, we want to notified by a push -- i.e. when user execute command `git push origin <some branch>`. This is where the whole confusion comes from. If you could either confirm or correct whether it means got notified for command `git commit` or `git push origin <some branch>`, it will be great.

Comment: Since as you’ve said a commit is local, the only way to “commit to a pull request” is by pushing to its branch. I agree that the wording is not perfect there. But yes, the notification would be triggered by a push, not a commit.

Comment: Thanks poke, mark your reply as answer. Thanks for the patience to explain to me. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you wish to monitor pushes to remote (I have a solution for local as well at the end) and for that you can use [GitHub webhooks](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/about-webhooks) as mentioned in @poke's response.

Just to give an alternate answer for anyone else looking to try it out. If you rather not build your own consumption pipeline, consider using [LightFlare](https://lightflare.bytebeacon.com) (I'm the creator) that has out of the box support of consuming Webhooks events from many services (github included) and notifies you at your choice(s) of destinations (slack / email etc ...).

[LightFlare](https://lightflare.bytebeacon.com) currently supports monitoring on services like:

- Infra: GCP, AWS, Azure, heroku
- Code/release: GitHub, bitbucket, netlify
- Commerce: shopify, gumroad
- More integrations based on our customers asks

With LightFlare, you can track local commits as well .. just have to add a git hook that curl's to your lightflare channel URL.